# How to create a "save" menu item in java. I have created the "save as " menu item but don't know how to create the "save" menu item

Tags: java, swing

```
jmi = jm.add(new JMenuItem("Save As...", 'V'));
       jm.addSeparator(); 
       jmi.addActionListener(e->{
           if ( jfc.showSaveDialog(EmployeeApp2.this)==
                   JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
               File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
               int size = (int) f.length();
               char ch[] = new char [size];

               try{
               FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
               fw.write(ch,0,size);
               fw.close();
               } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                   System.err.println("File unable to save");
               }catch (IOException excp){
                   System.err.println("IO");
               }

              String s = new String (ch);
              List.getData(s);
              repaint();

           }

       });
```

So basically what i wanted to is to create a "save" menu item in java. so that when the user click save the first time it opens a save dialog and ask the user to input the name of the file and save it. And when the user wants to save the same file again it should just automatically save the file without opening the save dialog box.

Comment: I would suggest to have to have a look at [How to use actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), the basic idea is, you need to know to what "Save to" saved to, so you and re-use it when using "Save"

Comment: Just keep track of which file was opened in a variable and use that as the location to save to

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is, when you call "Save as", you need to remember "where" you saved to (and/or allow "Save" to do something similar)

To my mind, this means a model...

```
public interface FileModel {
    public File getCurrentFile();
}

public interface MutableFileModel extends FileModel {
    public void setCurrentFile(File file);
}
```

The idea here is to restrict who can change the current file.

```
public class DefaultFileModel implements MutableFileModel {

    private File currentFile;

    public File getCurrentFile() {
        return currentFile;
    }

    public void setCurrentFile(File file) {
        currentFile = file;
    }
}
```

With a "default" implementation, you can pass this where ever `FileModel` or `MutableFileModel` is required

Next, we need to wrap up the functionality

```
public abstract class AbstractFileAction<M extends FileModel> extends AbstractAction {

    private M model;

    public AbstractFileAction(M model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    protected M getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}

public class SaveFileAction<M extends FileModel> extends AbstractFileAction<M> {

    public SaveFileAction(M model) {
        super(model);
        putValue(NAME, "Save");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        File file = getModel().getCurrentFile();
        if (file != null) {
            //...
        }
    }
}

public class SaveFileAsAction extends SaveFileAction<MutableFileModel> {

    public SaveFileAsAction(MutableFileModel model) {
        super(model);
        putValue(NAME, "Save As...");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
        putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        File file = //...
        getModel().setCurrentFile(file);
        super.actionPerformed(evt);
    }
}
```

Here, I've decided to use the `Action` API, as it provides functionality for self contained, re-usable and easily extendable classes, as you can see, the core functionality for `SaveFileAsAction` comes from the `SaveFileAction`, no need to repeat myself.

Then you just need to set it all up for the user...

```
DefaultFileModel model = new DefaultFileModel();

JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
menu.add(new SaveFileAction(model));
menu.add(new SaveFileAsAction(model));

JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
mb.add(menu);
```

Now, this is an overly simplified example, I might add an observer pattern to the model to generate events when the model was changed and update the state of the `SaveFileAction` or allow the `SaveFileAction` to prompt the user for a `File` if the value of the model was `null`, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Have a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks so much. I will just do ask you said and read more on "How to use Actions"  -@MasProgrammer

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SaveFile 
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {

          Frame SecondFrame = new JFrame();
          JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
          fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");
          int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog( SecondFrame);
     }
}
```